# TYPO3 8.7: Set page type programmatically

Tags: select, types, typo3, dropdown

Being new to TYPO3, I'm interested in finding out, how I can add a TYPO3 page type in the backend on page creation programmatically.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear, what do you try to achieve?
1) On creation of a new page, you want to create a custom page-type (doktype)? (Not possible)
2) On creation of a new page, you want to programmatically create another page?
3) ...

Comment: I created already the doktypes. Now as I click new Page I can see in dropdown the new doktype but this one is not selected as default. As I click on new Page I want to have my doktype as default selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/8.7/en-us/PageTsconfig/TopLevelObjects/Index.html?highlight=tcadefault) you can set a default value for each field of any table with **Page-/User-TSconfig**.

general:

```
TCAdefaults.<table>.<field> = <value>
```

specific:

```
TCAdefaults.pages.doktype = 123
```

(replace 123 with your doktype)